# difficult integral with bessel functions

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

$$\int_{0}^R \rho J_0\left(\frac \rho {\sqrt \tau} \right) J_0 \left(k_n \rho \right) d\rho = -\frac {{R^3}/{\sqrt \tau}}{x_n^2-{R^2}/{\sqrt \tau}} J_1\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt \tau}\right) J_0(x_n)$$

I want to show the above. Can anyone help?

Comment: any own work? ?

Comment: i can't think of something

Comment: A typo: $k_n=x_n$? Or some other relation?

Comment: $\ k_n=x_n /R   $ where $\ x_n $  are the zeros of bessel function $\ J_1 (x)=0 $